# Can't Update or Delete Plugins From Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I'm having trouble updating or deleting anything from the plugins folder of my Wordpress install. I've tried manually deleting the plugins via FTP, but get an error message that way. I also get an error via SSH, saying I don't have permission for those files.

The plugins folder is owned and in the group www-data. Everything else is owned by the username bitnami. I'm hosted on Amazon Lightsail.

How can I change the folder ownership of /Plugins/ to bitnami so that I can edit the contents?

Comment: Please note that questions which occur in the context of WordPress but which aren't actually about WordPress are considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. But I'm glad you seem to have found a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check to see how your WordPress install is managed. [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress) is a package manager, which means it probably manages updates and adding/removing plugins directly.

Another solution might be running this via SSH:

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo chmod 640 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
```

This was a solution on a [Bitnami Forum.](https://community.bitnami.com/t/cannot-update-delete-or-add-new-plugins-on-wordpress-aws-lightsail-have-tried-multiple-fixes-to-no-avail/67792)